# How to Concatenate a Select with the query()?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm use the query function, and what I want is to combine columns A, B, and C into a string with hyphens separating them. i.e. "2-4-6".

```
A|B|C
-|-|-
2|4|6
```

How could I do this?

I've tried the following but it returns an error:

```
=query(raw!A1:C, "select 'A & '-' & B & '-' &C")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(raw!A1:C),,999^99))), " ", "-"))
```

[image: 0]

---

or use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(raw!A:A&IF(raw!B:B="",,"-"&raw!B:B)&IF(raw!C:C="",,"-"&raw!C:C))
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to achieve this using the query function?

Comment: not like you imagine but I added one more alternative